# How to optimize serializing models data in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need an advice. Sometimes I have situations when in an API I need to retrive a lot of data from some db tables. And when I try to get all data - it takes a lot of time. So I use a little bicycle for retrieving data in a single query.

Example:

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_name1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    related_name2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    related_name3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_related_name1(self, obj):
        return self.values[obj.id].get('related_table1__name')

    def get_related_name2(self, obj):
        return self.values[obj.id].get('related_table1__related_table2__name')

    def get_related_name3(self, obj):
        return self.values[obj.id].get('related_table3__name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Collect all necessary data from BD.
        self.values = {}
        if self.instance:
            for some_model_values in self.instance.values(
                'id',
                'related_table1__name',
                'related_table1__related_table2__name',
                'related_table3__name'
            ).iterator():
                self.values[some_model_values['id']] = some_model_values

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'related_name1', 'related_name2', 'related_name3')
```

It works fine for situations when need to retrive a lot of data, but it takes more time in coding than simple serializer.
Is this a good idea to optimize data retrieving, or you have other solutions for this situation?

This solution makes 2 queries to DB for any queryset.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for SO. In my opinion it is a very bad idea. You're sacrificing code maintainability and readability. Keep your code simple. If you really need better performance I'd suggest you to use Redis and [django-cacheops](https://pypi.org/project/django-cacheops/) to cache your queries. I have very positive experience with these tools.

Comment: While it's not included in your question, I think your problem will probably be a lack of optimisation of your queries, most likely an N+1 select problem.  When you want to access, per-row, data from a related table make sure to add a `.prefetch_related(...)` to the queryset in the DRF view.  Given what you're describing, it sounds like a problem I've seen before, where rendering each row using a DRF serializer requires at least one additional round-trip to the database.

Comment: I agree that '.prefetch_related(...)' and '.select_related(...) 'can be useful for retriving all fields from related instance. But I collect only fields that using in this serializer. For example if related_table2 has 15 fields with data, and I need only name - I collect just one field.

Comment: Using annotate with these fields will be both efficient and readable IMO

Answer (score 0):

we can simply override the method `to_representation` in serializer.

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(SomeModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data.update({
       'related_name1': instance.related_table1.name,
       'related_name2': instance.related_table2.name
       # more fields & values
    })
    return data

  class Meta:
    model = SomeModel
    fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Your solution makes a query to DB for every related table, in the same time my solution makes 2 queries to DB for every queryset. I try to make less queries to DB.

Comment: We can use prefetch_related or select_related on query set.

Comment: If I understand the work of the '.select_related(...) ' correctly - it retrieves all fields from related instance. And if related_table2 has 15 fields with data - it collect all this fields. In my code - I collect only necessary fields for this serializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     value1 = serializer.CharField(source='related_table1.name', read_only=True)
     value2 = serializer.CharField(source='related_table1.related_table2.name')
     ............
     # and so on
     class Meta:
         model = ModelName
         fields = (
             'value1',
             'value2',
             ....
         )
```

I think, it is not so much to write it
Information about it: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: You write standard serializer solution, but it makes a lot of queries to collect all data. I try to optimize collecting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `prefetch_related` in the `view`/`viewset` which uses `SomeModelSerializer`? Something like

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from myapp.models import SomeModel
from myapp.api.v1.serializers import SomeModelSerializer


class SomeModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.prefetch_related(
        'related_table1',
        'related_table1__related_table2',
        'related_table3',
    )
```

Comment: Yes, I tested solution with select_related and prefetch_related and it works fine for little queryset, but for queryset with thousands entries and 5-10 related tables for collecting - it takes too much time (and collects a lot of useless in this case data).